# Domain forwarding/masking

Tags: dns, webserver, dnsmasq

We have to redirect/forward all HTTP(S) requests from one web server A to a web server B (which will show the downtime info) only if the server A is not accessible. Can we use DNS forwarding for this purpose ?

Is there any other way we can achieve this ?

Comment: Which protocol? HTTP?

Comment: both HTTP and HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

DNS multiple name/round Robin might me often used to a crude man load-balacing solution, but in reality is not indicated to a high availability solution. As it is mostly the client that regulates requests you have no absolutely no guarantees the client will get the IP address of the server that is working.

There are several possibilities for other solutions that can give you high availability, either hardware or software.

As for software solutions in Linux for high availability for the HTTP(S) protocol, have a look at [LVS](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org), [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org), [pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/) or [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org).

Of the three, the simpler to setup should be HAProxy or pound.

[An Introduction to HAProxy and Load Balancing Concepts](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-haproxy-and-load-balancing-concepts)

> WHAT POUND IS:
>   a reverse-proxy: it passes requests from client
>   browsers to one or more back-end servers.
>   a load balancer: it will
>   distribute the requests from the client browsers among several
>   back-end servers, while keeping session information.
>   an SSL wrapper:
>   Pound will decrypt HTTPS requests from client browsers and pass them
>   as plain HTTP to the back-end servers.
>   an HTTP/HTTPS sanitizer: Pound
>   will verify requests for correctness and accept only well-formed ones.
>   a fail over-server: should a back-end server fail, Pound will take
>   note of the fact and stop passing requests to it until it recovers.
>   a
>   request redirector: requests may be distributed among servers
>   according to the requested URL.

We use pound here for a very high traffic server. It is very lightweight, and besides distributing the load and handling the SSL negotiation, thus freeing resources in the web sources, it also capable of displaying a web page if none of the web servers are operational.

http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2009/03/emu-marketing-generating-useful-error-pages-with-pound/